# mysql view users vs admin users syntax inquiry

Tags: mysql

Setting up JDBC security realm with Glassfish and I came across this link that provides user control access (admin vs view users). here is the link for this tutorial.

```
 http://jugojava.blogspot.com.eg/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html?showComment=1459000091065#c232448315667617784
```

Few things I didn't understand in the guide and I hope if you can help. What do the lines below mean? (full sql code at the end of of the question)

```
KEY `fk_users_has_groups_groups1` (`group_id`),
KEY `fk_users_has_groups_users` (`user_id`),
```

I don't see any table named u but the code is using  u.*. The code at the very bottom doesn't have "u" table in it. However, I see the reference to "u" in the inner Join. Can I do select u. based on this INNER JOIN?

```
CREATE VIEW `v_user_role` AS
SELECT  u.username, u.password, g.group_name
FROM `user_groups` ug
INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
INNER JOIN `groups` g ON g.group_id =  ug.group_id;
```

Here is the full Code

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `group_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `group_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `group_desc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` char(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_groups` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`group_id`),
  KEY `fk_users_has_groups_groups1` (`group_id`),
  KEY `fk_users_has_groups_users` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_groups` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`group_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
); 

CREATE VIEW `v_user_role` AS
SELECT  u.username, u.password, g.group_name
 FROM `user_groups` ug
 INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
 INNER JOIN `groups` g ON g.group_id =  ug.group_id; 
INSERT  INTO `groups`(`group_id`,`group_name`,`group_desc`) VALUES 
  (1,'USER','Regular users'),
  (2,'ADMIN','Administration users');

INSERT  INTO `users`(`user_id`,`username`,`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`,`password`) VALUES 
  (1,'john','John',NULL,'Doe','6e0b7076126a29d5dfcbd54835387b7b'), /*john123*/
  (2,'admin',NULL,NULL,NULL,'21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'); /*admin*/

INSERT  INTO `user_groups`(`user_id`,`group_id`) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(2,2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) KEY indicates that those fields are indexed. The index is not unique. See [create index documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

2) The "u" is an [alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), specifically it is a table alias. You can use aliases to refer to a table or field name under a different name. An alias is specific to a query. The alias is defined in the from clause:

```
`users` u
```

Comment: Regarding the Alias, that's what I suspected  but what is confusing me is that the SELECT uses the alias u selecting u.username etc. before the reference u was mentioned few lines below in the INNER JOIN. can you do that? use the reference u  in SELECT and mention what it references later?. Is there a better way to have written this statement?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Do not forget, the select list is evaluated **after** the from clause, even though the select list is ahead of the from clause when you write the sql statement!